# expo notification topic subscription using expo server

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

I am trying to make a topic subscription to expo server

```
  const triggerNotificationHandler = () => {
    fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        to: pushToken,
        data: { extraData: 'Some data' },
        title: 'Sent via the app',
        body: 'This push notification was sent via the app!',
      }),
    });
  };
```

Is it possible to make a topic subscription and send notification to user using expo server
i want to send it to a group of people what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expo doesn't currently have support for topic subscription and broadcast. The alternative you have for now is to broadcast to all the user tokens. Or you can eject your Expo app and use firebase messaging that support topic broadcasting.